# Unable to use resource defined in resourcedictionary in code

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, silverlight-toolkit

my problem is as follows:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <toolkit:MenuItem Header="edit" x:Key="mnuEdit" x:Name="mnuEdit" Click="mnuEdit_Click" />
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

i am trying to add this menu item to context menu in code as `ctxmnuList.Items.Add(this.Resources["mnuEdit"] as MenuItem);`

but during runtime i am getting `InvalidOperationException` with error message as `Element is already the child of another element.`

kindly help for this issue. I am searching its solution from past 2 days.
Any help will be highly appreciated

Thanx anywayz

Comment: Obvious question: can you just define the `MenuItem` as part of `ctxmnuList` instead of as a resource?  Are you planning on adding this resource to more than one element or only to one?

Comment: actually... my requirements are like that i cant create static context menu. due to some performance issue (creating many contextmenuitem objects in page constructor), i thought of having them defined in page resource dictionary to grab some UI performance. And moreover this has worked for me on application bar iconbuttons and menuitems. i need to load them dynamically based on what user selects and what is default on the screen. i had defined them in page's resource dictionary and really gained massive ui performance.

Answer (score 0):

This ought to work for you:

```
var mnuEdit = (MenuItem)this.Resources["mnuEdit"];
this.Resources.Remove(mnuEdit);
ctxmnuList.Items.Add(mnuEdit);
```

Comment: In the same PhoneApplicationPage instance, it will fail.  In a new instance, it will work (`this.Resources` is not static).  Do you need it more than once in the same instance?  If so, why?  If you're trying to create it each time the context menu is requested via right-click, you might be doing this from the wrong angle, and you might either want to keep the ctxmnuList around, or change mnuEdit into a template, style, or UserControl, and then simply apply that template when you want to generate the context menu.  Or just keep mnuEdit in a field and remove it from ctxmnuList when it's unloaded

Comment: but do you think, menuitem class defined in Phone Tooljit from codeplex can be customized XAML way?

Comment: Yes, it looks like it can.  None of my suggestions require that you set its properties programmatically instead of through XAML.